# Generating graphs on-the-fly with JavaScript with mouseover "captions"

Tags: javascript

I am developing a backend that requires to have graphs with information associated in a javascript why. The idea is to reproduce something similar to Google Analytics/Webmaster Tools:

[image: example of graph]

I also like to reproduce the "hover" caption when someone moves throw the days.

Does anybody knows if this is possible to do it with JavaScript? It's not allowed to use jQuery, so no "use jQuery" replies please.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But we'd need to see the mark-up and code you're working with in order to help you.

Comment: @David Thomas: it will be simple, X-cord with days from 1 to 30 (or 31) and Y-cord with impresions, nothing more. I've no code because I've been asked yesterday about this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are loads of svg-based javascript libraries for drawing charts that support custom tooltips among other features.

My personal favourite is **[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)** which is a full-feautured stand-alone library.

The charting libraries of [Dojo](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/07/13/dive-into-dojo-charting/), [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-3) and [YUI3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/charts/) are also very good and support custom tooltips if you don't mind them being not standalone.

All of these libraries support at least IE7+, mobile devices and all other major browsers.

**I suggest using them instead of making your own javascript code** for charts. They are all amazingly customizable and unless you need a very special kind of charts these will work great for you.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytic's graphs are Flash, not JavaScript.

To draw graphs using JavaScript you can use SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) and I suggest [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). Take a look at it.